# 2D Array: Magic Square

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

The question I am working on is:

A square with the side length n is filled with numbers `1,2,3,...n2` is a magic square if the sum of elements in each row, column, and two diagonals is the same value.

Write a program that reads in a value of 16 values from the keyboard and tests whether they form a magic square when put into a `4 x 4` array. You need to test the following 2 features:

- Does each number of `1,2,...16` occur in user input? Tell the user to try again if they enter a number that they've already entered.
- When the numbers are put into a square, are the sums of rows, columns, and diagonals equal to each other?
- It must be done using two-dimensional array

I am having trouble with asking the user to try again if they enter a number that they have previously entered. And, numbers in `4 x 4` do not print. 
What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

This is the code I have so far:

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    int n =4;

    int[][] square = new int[n][n];

    int number = 0;
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <16; i++){
      number = num;
      System.out.print ("Enter a number: ");
      num = in.nextInt();

      int num_2 = 0;

      if (number==num || number==num_2) {
        System.out.println ("Try again.");
        System.out.println ("Enter a number: ");
        num_2 = in.nextInt();
      }
      if (num > 16){
        System.out.println ("Try again.");
        break;
      }
    }

    for (int i= 0; i < n; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        num+=square [i][j];
        System.out.print(square[i][j] + "\t");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please help me understand what do you want in 1st feature. I think there is a typo it should be from 1 to 16. Am I right?

Comment: you are right. I’m sorry about that, it is from 1 to 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code for 1st feature and add code for 2nd one.

```
int ar[][] = new int[4][4];
    System.out.println("Enter Numbers");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            boolean flag = false;
            int num = sc.nextInt();
            if (num > 16 || num < 1) {
                System.out.println("Please Enter number between 1 to 16");
                flag=true;
                j--;

            } else {
                for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l <= j; l++) {
                        if (ar[k][l] == num) {
                            System.out.println("This number already inserted...Please give another");
                            j--;
                            flag = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            if (!flag) {
                ar[i][j] = num;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you can't understand anything please ask. 
Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. I understand your code but it is not exactly what the question is asking. The program should tell the user that they entered a number that they've already previously entered, as they are entering the numbers. In your code, this is written after and it does not print. I am not sure if I am not completely understanding your code or if it is a problem. Can you please clarify? Thanks

Comment: @Kelsey Code is correct, the code under else part checks whether the user has already entered the number or not. Suppose if user enters 9 and then again enters 9 the code will print **"This number already inserted...Please give another"**. And also I am checking that numbers are between 1 and 16 therefore until all digits between 1 to 16 are entered, code will ask for it. Hope you understand. Try to run this code on your system and use diffirent numbers to check its validity.

Comment: I was not saying the code is incorrect. The code is correct and runs without any errors. However, it does not print "this number already inserted... Please give another" when the user enters the same number twice. I have tried multiple times. The question is asking the user to enter another number IF they have entered the same number twice. Hope you can help.

Comment: @Kelsey Sorry, my mistake... just add `flag=true;` after this statement  `System.out.println("Please Enter number between 1 to 16");`  and change `boolean flag = true;` to `boolean flag = false;`

Comment: @Kelsey I have made the changes in the above code, try to run it again.

Comment: Glad it worked...please upvote and mark it correct if you liked the solution :)